# How fast did Lake Agassiz and Lake Ojibway drain?

Tags: ice-age, glaciation, lakes

[Lake Agassiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Agassiz) and [Lake_Ojibway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Ojibway) drained around the time of the [8.2 kiloyear event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.2-kiloyear_event), [perhaps in a couple of pulses](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.quascirev.2021.107269), the first subglacially and the second when the glacial ice dam finally broke. Clearly these pulses were fast on a geological time scale, but how fast were they?

I found [one study](https://doi.org/10.1029/2021GL093919) reported that a flow through the Clearwater Lower Athabasca Spillway took 6-9 months.  Is this a lower bound on the length of the second pulse?